# jQuery - Refresh div when $.post()'s true

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make my jQuery code refreshing the div after deleting a post. My code looks like this:

```
$.post('/includes/classes/handler.php?do=postDelete', { postId: $postId }, 
    function(data) {
        $('.globalWrapper').fadeOut('slow').load(this).fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

The script deletes perfectly, and fades in/out fine, but the window is not refreshed. I've seen that you need a file for the load() function. But isn't there a way to refresh the div just? So that the PHP script I'm using to call posts is refreshed too?

**UPDATE**

HTML:

```
<div class='postHolder'>
 <div class='postMain'>
  <div class='postContent'>

  </div><!-- postContent end -->
 </div><!-- postMain end -->

  <div id='postDelete'>Her is my delete div which i'm calling to delete a post.</div>

</div><!-- postHolder end -->
```

.postHolder is the div that has to be removed.

Comment: change load(this) to load(data) - also, i'm thinking that what you want is probably to replace the html or at the very least the text, and not to use the load function at all. try html(data) instead?

Comment: I am trying to just refresh the div where my posts is, and not the returned data from php script, which I believe load(data) would?

Comment: As I understand it, you have a php file that deletes item from the page. You most likely have a php file which generates the items on the page. You need to call the file that generates the div again. You can't just 'refresh' the div randomly and hope that the browsers knows you performed server side actions. you must walk it through.

Comment: Yeah, I get that I have to call the div that regenerates the post's. But I thought that by loading the wrapper again it would do that. But I get that it cant.

Comment: If you wanted to do that, you would have to have a JSON object encoded and passed to you when you perform Delete actions. This requires more programming than is visible here and is likely more complicated than the solution that you need.

Comment: You could perform a $.get request within the function(data) to refresh your div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean refresh the div? You need to go grab what you want in the div and place it there using a get request. the div does not know where it came from. You could add an attribute to the div so you know where it came from and use that to refresh the div.

How about, instead of reloading the div, just do the `post` delete as you are doing and then just remove the post from the html. No need to actually go off and return a list of records to refresh the div.

Use some jquery like this to remove the post.

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

Comment: "How about, instead of reloading the div..." I think this is what I am trying to do. I just want to not refresh page and remove the post from the page.

Comment: I think I'll use this one. I just need to get the right code. The div that I have to get remove(); on is before the #postDelete. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: well, update your question with the html and i will see if i can help. I am not a master of jquery myself.

Comment: try `$(this).closest('#postDelete').remove();`. when you get it working, you can add fadeout to it i think

Comment: it's not #postDelete that ha to be removed.. It's .postHolder.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.postHolder').remove();` (i just changed this to look for the class)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8687/discussion-between-valamas-and-kolind)

Comment: I used Valamas' $(this).closest('.postHolder').remove();... :) thanks to everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example correctly, you're POSTING the deletion of the post to handler.php and trying to load `this` into the `globalWrapper`. The problem is that `this` isn't what you think it is. Try logging it to console to see what it tells you.

If you pass a valid resource (one that returns HTML) into `load()`, it should work as expected.

[update] More accurately... sort of as expected. The way you have your functions chained, you're probably imagining that it will fade in after the resource is loaded, but I don't think it will (haven't tested)... it will fade in after the call is made. The fade-in should be part of the loading's success handler.

[update 2] I assumed based on your written requirement that you wanted to reload content, but if you really just want to remove it, I think Valamas is bringing you in a better direction.

Comment: How would I have to log it in console? I have Firebug but I am a bit unsure of how to use it.

Comment: The old-school way of this kind of debugging was "alert". Do the exact same thing but instead of `alert(this)` (which would just tell you [object Object] I think) you would add the line `console.log(this)` which will show you an object in the Firebug console that you can actually dig into. Even the console method is scoffed at by better debuggers than me (who use breakpoints and all that jazz) but at least it's something!

Comment: I haven't thought just removing it before Valamans wrote it. I just can't figure out how to catch the div now.. I have a div which holds the post, like a wrapper - and when #postDelete is clicked and deletion triggered I want the postHolder (the wrapper) to be removed. But I can't figure out how to do this. How do I select previous the #postDelete?

Comment: As Valamas mentions, show your structure in your original question, and we'll be properly equipped to provide DOM-traversal or selection methods for deleting it.